# Fletcher32: is the limit of 360 in Wikipedia wrong?

Tags: java, optimization, hashcode, checksum

The Wikipedia article about the Fletcher checksum (currently) says that for Fletcher 32, [the sums need to be reduces after 360 steps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher%27s_checksum#Optimizations). However, according to my test, it is enough to reduce after 720 steps. Is the limit of 360 in Wikipedia simply wrong, or did I make a mistake in my test?

Bonus points for any other possible optimization :-) Except for hardcoding the limit.

My test case (Java, but the same applies to C or C#):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    byte[] data = new byte[2 * 1024];
    Arrays.fill(data, (byte) 255);
    for (int limit = 1; limit <= 721; limit++) {
        System.out.println("Test limit " + limit);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
            if (getFletcher32(data, i, 1) != getFletcher32(data, i, limit)) {
                System.out.println("Stop at limit=" + limit + " index=" + i);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

// bytes: the data
// length: the number of bytes (must be an even number)
// limit: when to reduce the sums (only used for testing)
static int getFletcher32(byte[] bytes, int length, int limit) {
    int s1 = 0xffff, s2 = 0xffff;
    for (int i = 0; i < length;) {
        for (int end = Math.min(i + limit, length); i < end;) {
            int x = ((bytes[i++] & 0xff) << 8) | (bytes[i++] & 0xff);
            s2 += s1 += x;
        }
        s1 = (s1 & 0xffff) + (s1 >>> 16);
        s2 = (s2 & 0xffff) + (s2 >>> 16);
    }
    s1 = (s1 & 0xffff) + (s1 >>> 16);
    s2 = (s2 & 0xffff) + (s2 >>> 16);
    return (s2 << 16) | s1;
}
```

The test prints:

```
Test limit 1
Test limit 2
...
Test limit 720
Test limit 721
Stop at limit=721 index=721
```

Meaning the result is the same for limit 1 up to 720, and only with limit 721 the checksum is different (meaning, it is incorrect).

Comment: Your test only proves that the result at 720 is the same as the result at 360.

Comment: @EJP I have changed the test case to loop over all possible limits, and stop at the first difference. Is there anything else to prove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised my mistake now, and see that both Wikipedia *and* my implementation are correct...

The reason is, the Wikipedia article uses a limit of 360 *words* (each word two bytes), while my implementation uses a limit of 720 *bytes*.

As for optimizations: possibly the final reduction step could be simplified a little bit, but that wouldn't change much.

Answer (score 1):

I see I was pretty wrong with my old answer, so I wrote this trivial loop which checks for `int` overflow:

```
long s1 = 0xffff, s2 = 0xffff;
for (int n=0; ; ++n) {
    final int a = 0xff;
    final int b = 0xff;
    final int x = (a << 8) | b;
    s2 += s1 += x;
    System.out.format("%4d %08X %08X\n", n, s1, s2);
    if ((s2 & 0xFFFFFFFFL) != s2) break;
}
```

The output ends with

```
358 0167FE98 FDD3022C
359 0168FE97 FF3C00C3
360 0169FE96 100A5FF59
```

which shows us that we must stop before the 360th iteration in order for `s2` not to overflow.

---

There's one difference to the presented algorithm. The line

```
return (s2 << 16) | s1;
```

should read

```
return (s2 << 16) | (s1 & 0xffff);
```

as the original type is `uint16_t`, but this doesn't matter, because of `s1` being small.

Comment: Yes, I assume that `s2 += s1 += x;` will overflow at the earliest with all bytes at 255. With Random.nextBytes we can't be sure we have the worst case. Maybe I should use `long s2` and verify (within the loop) that it is never higher than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`... Ah, ok, in that case it overflows at limit 509.

Comment: Try my initialization out, it answers your question. It's deterministic, so you'll surely see that the results for 359 and 720 differ. You assumption is wrong, 255 is not the worst case.

Comment: Using `long` could work fine, but it'll need a different reduction and whatever. Fletcher is a crappy algorithm designed for crappy (for today's standards) CPU's so I'm not sure.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you are seeing. I tested with random data (your suggested code and using different seed values as well), and the returned checksum is the same. Of course using `long` would only for verifying there is no overflow, not for the real (production) code. But I believe the same reduction could be used when using `long` (I don't see why not).

Comment: @ThomasMueller: Apologies, I made an error in my test. I'll try again and come back then. Concerning `long`, on a 64-bit JVM there's no penalty for using it and you could save quite some reductions. For really large arrays it could be advantageous to do a final reduction using modulus instead of many simple reductions in-between.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! I also made a mistake, as I forgot to mention the method requires that the length is an even number. I will try using a `long` and verify how much faster that would be. I guess it wouldn't be faster on Android, but on a 64-bit JVM it should be, that's true.

Comment: @ThomasMueller: I completely rewrote my answer. Are you sure you need Fletcher? It's fast but it's not much faster than e.g. murmurhash and it's a crap.

Comment: I found the problem now, it was a silly mistake on my side. Thanks a lot for your help, and I will +1 your answer, even thought it is not the correct answer. I use Fletcher as a simple, fast checksum (not as a hash function), and for that I believe it is more appropriate than MurmurHash.